# MD5 in Object-C and C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, md5

I have a method written in c# to get md5:

```
    public static string encryptPasswordWithMd5(string password)
    {
        MD5 md5Hasher = MD5.Create();
        byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            sb.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Now I need to implement the same function using objective-c, how to do it?

ps: I have used the way here http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1509152&tstart=96

the code in objc is

-(NSString *) encryptPasswordWithMd5: (NSString *) _password 
{
    const char * cStr = [_password cStringUsingEncoding: NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];

```
unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CC_MD5(cStr, strlen(cStr), result);

return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",

        result[0], result[1],

        result[2], result[3],

        result[4], result[5],

        result[6], result[7],

        result[8], result[9],

        result[10], result[11],

        result[12], result[13],

        result[14], result[15]

        ];
```

}

but they don't get the same result. take 'admin' as example, c# is "19a2854144b63a8f7617a6f225019b12" but the objc is "0CC175B9C0F1B6A831C399E269772661";

Answer (score 1):

Check [this links](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1509152&tstart=96) (last post). It shows how to calculate MD5 hash in Objective-C.

BTW: You can also simplify MD5 computation in C# a bit

```
public static string encryptPasswordWithMd5(string password)
{
    var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    var originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(password);
    var encodedBytes = md5.ComputeHash(originalBytes);
    return BitConverter.ToString(encodedBytes);
}
```